# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'productId3' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, hql

I get an error `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'productId3' in 'where clause'` when trying to run this query:

```
public Vendor getVendorId(ProductInfo productInfo) { 
        return (Vendor) this.sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery(
                        "select vendorId from Product where productId3 = :id")
                .setParameter("id", productInfo).uniqueResult();
    }
```

The class Product looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID2")
    private Integer productId2;

    public void setProductId2(Integer productId2){
        this.productId2 = productId2;
    }

    public Integer getProductId2(){
        return productId2;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID3")
    private ProductInfo productId3;

    public void setProductId3(ProductInfo productId3){
        this.productId3 = productId3;
    }

    public ProductInfo getProductId3(){
        return productId3;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="VENDOR_ID")
    private Vendor vendorId;

    public void setVendorId(Vendor vendorId){
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
    }

    public Vendor getVendorId(){
        return vendorId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="productId2")
    private Set<ProductRevision> productRevisions;

    public void setProductRevisions(Set<ProductRevision> productRevisions){
        this.productRevisions = productRevisions;
    }

    public Set<ProductRevision> getProductRevisions(){
        return productRevisions;
    }
}
```

Why do I get this error? I don't understand why it can't find the column as the name is exactly the same. Thanks for your help!

/D

Comment: You can start by setting the showSql parameter with 1 and checking the output query and posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
select p.vendorId from Product p where p.productId3 = :id
```

Comment: Btw, if you don't mind could you explain why my initial query didn't work? Thanks!

Comment: sql queries wont work as such with Hibernate/JPA    see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language

Answer (score 0):

Forgive the fussy response, but one thing that might HQL clearer for you is to rename your fields on the `Product` class.

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="PRODUCT_ID3")
    private ProductInfo productInfo;

    public void setProductInfo(ProductInfo productInfo){
        this.productInfo = productInfo;
    }
```

And similarly for the `vendorId` field. Then your HQL reads much better. It is clear that you are dealing with entities and not sql columns.

```
    public Vendor getVendorId(ProductInfo productInfo) { 
        return (Vendor) this.sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery(
                    "select p.vendor from Product where productInfo = :productInfo")
            .setParameter("productInfo", productInfo).uniqueResult();
    }
```